# Copying and Pasting RPG Code

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

Is there a way to copy and paste RPG code. Like maybe make it into a text file so one can copy and paste? I'm wanting to ask for assistance on a program but am hoping not to have to rewrite the code during the process to do so.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you are just learning RPG, you shouldn't be using SEU as it stopped being updated at v6.1 of the operating system. (As of 4/15/2016 we are at v7.3). There are a lot of things in RPG now that SEU just doesn't understand. Instead you should be using RDi. This is a GUI IDE that you can run on Windows or Linux, and it supports the entire RPG syntax. It also supports cut and paste control keys Ctrl-C, Ctrl-X, Ctrl-V that you are likely used to.

Comment: You could use MiWorkplace. https://miworkplace.com/. It is inexpensive.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please tell us which tools are you using? If you can't copy / past the code I assume it's Client Access for terminal emulation and SEU / PDM for code editing.

In this case you can simply edit your keyboard settings and assign copy / paste / cut functionality for a combination of c / v / x + ctrl keys. 
Just go to Edit -> Preferences -> Keyboard menu in your terminal emulator and press customize button.

There are also some free tools, like [RPG NextGen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpgnextgen/) which can allow you to work on remote source file, almost like you were using IDE. 
You may also want to try built in tools for downloading / uploading the sources to IBM i (send file to host / receive file from host) but it's a bit complex and not really worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you aren't so used to RPG programming ... this is a step by step guide to copy and past some rows of code from a source code to a text file on your PC:

1) You have to know where is your source code, and you may have some auth as a PGMR to view your source

2) Open with SEU (the standard IBMi editor) your source
STRSEU SRCFILE(YOURLIB/QRPGLESRC) SRCMBR(YOURMBR) TYPE(SQLRPGLE) OPTION(5)

3) Now you can copy and paste part of your code drawing a rectangular with your mouse and edit-copy and edit-paste on your PC

You can also copy source code to a txt file on IFS with this command
CPYTOIMPF FROMFILE(YOURLIB/YOURFILESRC YOURMBR) TOSTMF('/yourifspath/yourmbr.txt') STMFCCSID(*PCASCII) RCDDLM(*CRLF) DTAFMT(*FIXED)

Comment: I'm sorta new to RPG programming and the book we are using for our college course doesnt give instructions for things like this.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to move source code between my PC and an iSeries and I don't have RDi, I tend to use FTP.

This is from a windows command line:

```
H:\>ftp 192.168.1.1
Connected to 192.168.1.1.
220-QTCP at 192.168.1.1.
220 Connection will close if idle more than 500 minutes.
User (192.168.1.1:(none)): myuser
331 Enter password.
Password:
230 MYUSER logged on.
ftp> ascii
200 Representation type is ASCII nonprint.
ftp> put C:\Users\myuser\MYPGM.txt MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.MYPGM
200 PORT subcommand request successful.
150 Sending file to member MYPGM in file QRPGLESRC in library MYLIB.
226 File transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 528 bytes sent in 0.22Seconds 2.38Kbytes/sec.
ftp> quit
221 QUIT subcommand received.
```

If you have trouble reading this mess, first type `ftp 192.168.1.1` where `192.168.1.1` is the IP address or host name of the iSeries you're trying to connect to. It will prompt for your user name and password. After, type `ascii` and press enter. This will convert text to EBCDIC when uploading and ASCII when downloading. To upload something, type `put C:\Users\myuser\MYPGM.txt MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.MYPGM` where `C:\Users\myuser\MYPGM.txt` is the source code on your PC and `MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.MYPGM` is the library, source physical file and source member you want the code to go to. To download, use `get` instead of `put` like this: `get MYLIB/QRPGLESRC.MYPGM C:\Users\myuser\MYPGM.txt`. After you can type `quit` to exit the ftp session.

Be warned that this will *replace* any existing code in the given member or file. Also be sure that the library and source physical file exist on the iSeries before uploading or the system will create a regular file instead of a source physical file. The member doesn't have to exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Mocha TN5250, in the command line type: `call qcmd`, then right click and choose paste. It also works in IBM i Access for Web.